# Diffrent query in one function codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I use Codeigneter and I make a search function and in my function I want run two diffrent query and I want show them in diffrent table, How I can do that [Sorry I can't show the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oulOy.jpg)

This is My code:

My controller

```
function showDetail(){
        // Retrieve the posted search term.
        $detailTiket = $this->input->get('ticket_id');
        // Use a model to retrieve the results.
        $data["result"]= $this->tracking_model->showDetail($detailTiket);
        $data1["result"]= $this->tracking_model->showDetail2($detailTiket);

        // Pass the results to the view.
        $this->load->view('tracking/tiket_detail',$data,$data1);
    }
```

My Model

```
function showDetail($detailTiket)
    {   
        if($detailTiket==""){
            $detailTiket = "";
        }

        $showDetailTiket=$this->db->query("My Query1");

        return $detailTiketDown->result();
        }

function showDetail2($detailTiket)
    {   
        if($detailTiket==""){
            $detailTiket = "";
        }

        $detailTiketDown=$this->db->query("My query2");

        return $detailTiketDown->result();
        }
```

My view

```
<table Width='800'>  

        <?php
        foreach($data as $row){?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->ticket_id; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->created_time; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->start_IT; ?></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->estimasi_selesai; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: cyan">
            <td><b><?php echo $row->Status; ?></b></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
        <?php } ?>
                </table>
                </center>
                </div>



<div>
<table Width='1000'>
<?php foreach($data1 as $rows){ ?>  
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows->Tgl_Waktu; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows->PIC; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows->Tracking_Ticket; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows->Keterangan_Ticket; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows->File_Pendukung; ?></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
        <?php }?>
        </table>
```

Comment: you can able to run mutiple query and return the value as array like this return array($first_query_result,$second_query_result);

Comment: show your related code

Comment: @JYoThI, i have added my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass data like Associative array to view

change your controller like this

**Controller**:

```
$data["result"]= $this->tracking_model->showDetail($detailTiket);
$data["result1"]= $this->tracking_model->showDetail2($detailTiket);

// Pass the results to the view.
$this->load->view('tracking/tiket_detail',$data);
```

**view:**

**Table1 :**

```
 foreach($result as $row)
  {
     //for first result 
  }
```

**Table2:**

```
foreach($result1 as $row1)
  {
     //for second result 
  }
```

Comment: glad to help you @RizkiPahlevi